# Error while install R tm package "unable to load shared object tm.so"

Tags: r, linux, package, tm, linux-mint

While installing R package tm through:

install.packages("tm")

Also tried install.packages("tm", dependencies = T)

All things seemed to be right until this message appeared:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>    unable to load shared object 'home/user/anaconda2/lib/R/library/tm/libs/tm.so':
>     /home/user/anaconda2/lib/R/library/tm/libs/tm.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKS4_
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: loading failed
>   * removing ‘/home/user/anaconda2/lib/R/library/tm’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status

Also, it happened while installing other packages e.g. wordcloud

My R version info:

> latform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             linux-gnu
>   system         x86_64, linux-gnu
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          4.1
>   year           2017
>   month          06
>   day            30
>   svn rev        72865
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) 
>   nickname       Single Candle

So, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a compilation issue.  [This thread covers a similar issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3885) and suggests checking to make sure the R is compiled with the same compiler as the package - however, that could be a **conda**-specific issue.  Person in this case overcame same error by reinstalling R.